# Free memory after spalloc and sparse array construction

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a loop that creates a sparse array block by block. The matrix has a generous preallocation in order to speed up the construction. Is it possible (or necessary) to free up the preallocated memory after the construction of the sparse array?

A brief justification of this code. The sparse matrix a is T x P, and shifts is an R x Z x P matrix of index shifts. The function user_function applies the shifts, and uses the sparse constructor behaviour of summing repeated indices. Before this sum the size of the matrix is R * nnz(a), but the size after is less. Then, a threshold operation further reduces the size of the result to make it fit comfortably in memory.

This blockwise construction seemed to be the best way to avoid pre-allocating all values before the sparse constructor and threshold operation.

```
alloc_size = 1000000000 / 8;  % numerator is memory size of double array

out = spalloc(length(taxis), R * Z, alloc_size);
for rr = 1: R
    % r index is the remainder value of modulus operator
    savei = (0: (Z - 1)) * R + rr;
    % user_function allocates 3 R * nnz(a) vectors
    % result size is then reduced by repeated index summing and threshold
    out(:, savei) = user_function(a, squeeze(shifts(rr, :, :)), theshold);
end

if nnz(out) > alloc_size
    disp('exceeded number of preallocated results')
end
```

Comment: I don't think so...In the general case, I think you have to construct a new sparse, copy the content of the first one into it, then delete the original. But from the code you posted, it seems you can predict exactly how and where the non-zeros will go, so ... why not use that information in sparse()?

Comment: Also note that alloc_size represents the *number of elements*, not the number of bytes. Also, 1B allocated elements will consume 8GB of RAM, so yes, I think it's desirable to remove unused elements :)

Comment: Tried to clean up the question to make it more evident why I can not predict the number of elements that will eventually make it to the out matrix.The number of elements that go into the making the output (R * Z * nnz(a)) are far too many to store in memory at once.